# Running selenium-server alongside Scrapy - can't get Chrome Remote running

Tags: python, linux, selenium, ssh, scrapy

community,

**Quick intro:**
I'm rather new to Python and trying to run a Scrapy script to scrape a real estate-website (www.immoweb.be). Unfortunately, i encountered Incapsula protection on the website which requires me to run Selenium first so I can access the site through a real browser.

I access my remote server using SSH, starting selenium-server with (agora is project folder with chromedriver binary):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/<username>/agora
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar webdriver.chrome.driver=agora
```

Output:

```
14:53:51.308 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
14:53:51.539 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.111-b01
14:53:51.539 INFO - OS: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 amd64
14:53:51.602 INFO - v2.53.1, with Core v2.53.1. Built from revision a36b8b1
14:53:51.897 INFO - Driver provider     org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS,   ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, v
ersion=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
14:53:51.897 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver     registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS,   browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}] does not match the 
current platform LINUX
14:53:51.898 INFO - Driver class not found:  com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
14:53:51.898 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
14:53:51.899 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=MAC, browserName=safari,   version=}] does not match the current pla
tform LINUX
14:53:51.918 INFO - Driver class not found:  org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
14:53:51.918 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
14:53:52.133 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to:  http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
14:53:52.133 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

I don't think there is anything out of the ordinary here.
Then I boot up Scrapy in my virtualenv (in a second SSH window):

```
scrapy shell
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Remote(
...    command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
...    desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

which throws the following:

```
2016-12-28 15:03:25 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG:  POST http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session {"requiredCapabilities": {},    "desiredCapabilities
": {"version": "", "platform": "ANY", "browserName": "chrome",  "javascriptEnabled": true}}
```

This then hangs for +/- 1 min and throws the following error in my selenium-server shell:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux
3.16.0-4-amd64 x8 6_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 60.98 seconds Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03' System info: host: 'agora', ip: '10.132.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java .version: '1.7.0_111' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
        ... 14 more 15:04:28.463 WARN - Exception: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux
3.16.0-4-amd64 x8 6_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 60.98 seconds Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03' System info: host: 'agora', ip: '10.132.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-4-amd64', java .version: '1.7.0_111' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

(output in my scrapy shell is similar)

I found some fragmented info online about using xvfb or pyvirtualdisplay but none seem to be giving a real explanation on how I should sort this out. Could somebody here on Stack Overflow help me?

**Some extra background:**

The server I run is a Google Cloud Service ("Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)")

Java version is 1.7.0_111

Python version is 3.4.2 (via virtualenv - I installed scrapy & selenium via pip)

Comment: What if you try to explicitly state the Chrome Webdriver path?

Comment: You're trying to start non-headless browser in your VPS. Can you even execute Chrome on your server? You can always try switching to something else, usually people run something headless like PhantomJS.

Comment: starting Chrome gives me an error as well (no display). After googling a bit, I believe I need to create a 'fake' display via xvfb or pyvirtualdisplay, but still haven't found how I can run this next to the rest of the script.

PhantomJS is no option because the site is Incapsula protected. It has to be a real browser accessing (they use a whitelist)

I tried explicitly stating the Chrome webdriver path but that doesn't help